# Javascript json

Tags: php, javascript, json

does anyone know what this is not working? i have been trying for days now.

```
function loadContent(obj, getcmt)
{
var params = $(obj).attr('href').split('?');

$.get(BASE_DIR+'content/load.php?'+params[1],
     function(json) {
       var result = eval('('+json+')');
       if (result.returnval == 1) {
         $('#content').fadeOut('fast', function() { $(this).html(result.content).fadeIn('slow'); });

       }
    });
return false;
}
```

Firebug just give an error "missing } after property list"
and link to jquery. and another debugger show json as the reason why.

any help is greatly appreciated!

**EDIT:**

The top work fine but the following dont work:

```
<div id="content">
    <a href="{$content.item_url}" onclick="return loadContent2(this, 'page', '2')">
</a>
</div>
```

how ever if the single quote in onClick is not there, it work. like so:

```
<div id="content">
    <a href="{$content.item_url}" onclick="return loadContent2(this, "page", "2")">
</a>
</div>
```

However the function in question loadContent2 does not work.

Comment: Among the problems here is an attempt to parse JSON using `eval` (slow, inefficient, unsafe and hard to debug) instead of using jQuery's built in JSON response handler.

Comment: Is the JSON string valid?  It sounds like not.

Comment: What do you see in firebug for the ajax request BASE_DIR+'content/load.php?'+params[1]?

Comment: If the debugger is showing the JSON as the problem, then your issue is probably that the JSON isn't JSON. Hard to say for sure though — you haven't shared it with us! A [lint](http://jsonlint.com) would be useful though.

Comment: it's been working for a few years now, just all of a sudden, it failed....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it using jQuery's built-in tools:

```
function loadContent(obj, getcmt) {
    var params = $(obj).attr('href').split('?');
    $.getJSON(BASE_DIR+'content/load.php?'+params[1], function(json) {
        if (json.returnval == 1) {
            $('#content').fadeOut('fast', function() { 
                $(this).html(json.content).fadeIn('slow');
            });
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

This uses [`$.getJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) which is awesome.

if that has problems, check your response:

```
$.getJSON(BASE_DIR+'content/load.php?'+params[1], function(json) {
    console.debug(json);
});
```

Comment: that's more efficient, but it turn out the error is html 'a' tag with other functions seem to failed?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking... could you update your question?

Comment: This loadContent2(this, 'page', '2') in onclick prevent the fadeout and fade in from working. but changing to loadThumb(this, "page", "2") allow fadein and out to work, but not loadContent2; .